# Water meniscus oscillation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, surface-tension, vibrations

What is the general technique for obtaining the differential equation for water meniscus oscillation inside a container?

In case of the simplest mode, sloshing, we can find out the frequency without much heavy calculations (of course using some assumptions like plane surface and etc.)

But in case of higher modes,how to find the normal frequencies?
What is the differential equation associated with the vibration?

Comment: Isn't this just a damped spring-like equation where the surface tension acts as the restoring force and the viscosity provides the damping?

Comment: It should not be so because the forces are very different in nature.For simplest mode sloshing,it never follows from the simple damped spring equation.